# MUMmer plot error. Line 884. What to do?

Tags: errors

My third year comp sci friend got me this far, I hope you guys can help me with the last inch! For the record, I have practically no coding experience. I am using the 3.9.4 alpha version of MUMmer.

Here is the manual I have been following: http://mummer.sourceforge.net/examples/

I am at part 2.2.2 Running the Mummer plot, and I type in the final line to generate the plot.

I type:

`mummerplot -x "[0,8666124]" -y "[0,9025688]" -postscript -p mummer mummer.mums`

And the error is:

```
Can't use 'defined(%hash)' (Maybe you should omit the defined ()?) at /usr/bin/mummerplot line 884
```

Line at 884:

```
if ( defined (%$rref) ) {                                                                                                            #-- skip reference sequence or set atts from hash
        if ( !exists ($rref->{$idR}) ) { next; }
        else { ($refoff, $reflen, $refdir) = @{$rref->{$idR}}; }
```

Its perl

Comment: Hi could you please present your code inline, e.g. copy and paste? It is hard to read as an image. This looks like Perl, could you confirm this?

Comment: Cross-posted on biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/476874/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and I solved by removing `defined` and writing only `if (%$rref)` in the mummerplot code. You have to do this for all the lines that you have it. There should be six lines to correct in this way .

You can find an explanation of why [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined), that tells that the function `defined`:

> Returns a Boolean value telling whether EXPR has a value other than the undefined value undef. If EXPR is not present, $_ is checked.

And then:

> Use of `defined` on aggregates (hashes and arrays) is no longer supported. It used to report whether memory for that aggregate had ever been allocated. You should instead use a simple test for size:
> `if (%a_hash)   { print "has hash members\n"   }`

Comment: @KamilSJaron thank you but to be honest the code is written in C and I am not really expert on this. Anyway, I tried to add more details that is what has helped to me .

Comment: This is totally enough for people to get the idea that it's just an outdated part of the code, good job in figuring it out!